# How do I use hook_search_api_solr_search_results_alter() to alter search results?

Tags: 8, search

I want to alter the results of a Drupal 8.x search_api_solr search using hook_search_api_solr_search_results():

```
function sbn_search_api_solr_search_results_alter(\Drupal\search_api\Query\ResultSetInterface $result_set, 
                                                     \Drupal\search_api\Query\QueryInterface $query, 
                                                       \Solarium\QueryType\Select\Result\Result $result) {
 $resultset_data = $result->getData();
  // Get docs in response results
  $results = $resultset_data['response']['docs'];
  foreach ($results as $id => &$item) {
    // get the doc and array id
  }
}
```

I know that the docs I seek are in the search results:

```
dsm($result);
```

returns

```
stdClass Object
(
    [__CLASS__] => Solarium\QueryType\Select\Result\Result
    [numfound:protected] => 5
    [maxscore:protected] => 1.8644972
    [nextcursormark:protected] => 
    [documents:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [__CLASS__] => Solarium\QueryType\Select\Result\Document
                    [fields:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [ss_search_api_id] => entity:node/47:en
                            [ss_search_api_language] => en
                            [score] => 1.8644972
                        )

 ...
    [data:protected] => Array
        (
            [response] => Array
                (
                    [numFound] => 5
                    [start] => 0
                    [maxScore] => 1.8644972
                    [docs] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [ss_search_api_id] => entity:node/47:en
                                    [ss_search_api_language] => en
                                    [score] => 1.8644972
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [ss_search_api_id] => entity:file/85:en
                                    [ss_search_api_language] => en
                                    [score] => 1.784599
                                )
```

Let's say that the doc in question that I want to remove from `$result` object is:

```
$resultset_data['response']['docs'][$id]
```

How do I alter the `$result` object to remove this doc from results?  Every attempt I have made to access the `$result` object as an array has resulted in these types of errors:

> Error: Cannot use object of type Solarium\QueryType\Select\Result\Result as array

> Error: Cannot access protected property Solarium\QueryType\Select\Result\Result::$response

Any suggestions or documentation on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I have installed search_api, search_api_solr and search_api_attachments.  The View that I am reading with the hook is a Solr indexed view returning solr index extracts.

I discovered this was how to read the result rows:

```
  $result_items = $result_set->getResultItems();
  // Iterate through doc ids
  foreach ($result_items as $docid => $value) {
    // process info from $docid and/or $value
  }
```

**$docid** will be the Solr document id, i.e.: **entity:node/47:en**

In my case, all the information I need, *entity type* and *entity id*, are in the document id.

If I want to remove the result row:

```
unset($result_items[$docid]);
```

And at the end of the hook:

```
$result_set->setResultItems($result_items);
```